# Google Analytics didnt export old data to BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, gcloud, google-analytics-4

I have an app that has been published since 2021 and Google Analytics already generated a lot of reports. I wanted to export all the data from the reports to BigQuery and I setup the link using their tutorial: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9358801?hl=en.

But all the data present in BigQuery is the data from the day after I setup the link between them.

Is there some way to export the previous data to BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get historical data from GA4 to BigQuery. It starts exporting since you have setup connection.

I recommend to setup GA4 - BigQuery link at the same time you create GA4 property.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Go to Google analytics, download your historical data as CSV.
2. Open your CSV file with Google Sheets
3. In Google Sheets got to extensions --> Add-ons --> search for BigQuery Uploader for sheets
4. Once you have the add-on, click on the add-on under extensions, then "Run manual upload now"

Your historical data should now be in BigQuery.

Comment: What do you do if the data has more rows than google sheets can handle?

Comment: Please provide the information where all data in GA can be downloaded.